# join two tables and pick one row from the second table if a field is set in second table otherwise select any row

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have two tables in sqlite -

```
CREATE TABLE adverts ( 
    _id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title          TEXT,
    created_date   TEXT,
    details        TEXT,
    price          TEXT,
    codition       TEXT,
    phone          TEXT,
    alt_phone      TEXT,
    address        INTEGER,
    expiry_date    TEXT,
    ad_serial      TEXT,
    active         INTEGER,
    users_id       INTEGER,
    type_id        INTEGER,
    area_id        INTEGER,
    city_id        INTEGER,
    subCategory_id INTEGER,
    bestDeals      TEXT,
    wanted         TEXT,
    category_id    INTEGER,
    hits           TEXT,
    check_date     TEXT,
    u_email        TEXT,
    ip_address     TEXT,
    active_status  TEXT,
    premium        TEXT,
    language       TEXT,
    updated_by     TEXT,
    staff_note     TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY ( users_id ) REFERENCES users ( _id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( type_id ) REFERENCES type ( _id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( area_id ) REFERENCES area ( _id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( city_id ) REFERENCES city ( _id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( subCategory_id ) REFERENCES subcategory ( _id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( category_id ) REFERENCES category ( _id ) 
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE images ( 
    _id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT,
    path        TEXT,
    adverts_id  INTEGER,
    default_img TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY ( adverts_id ) REFERENCES adverts ( _id ) 
);
```

I need to write a query that selects data joining the two tables that selects a row with the row from images that has default_img set as 1 otherwise it can select any row from images joined to adverts table.
EDIT: There are 4 or 5 rows in the table images. only 0 or 1 rows will be set to 1. So the final rows will contain some columns from adverts table joined to the rows in the images table if the default_img is set to 1 otherwise it will select any rows corresponding to the advert with default_img=0.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following brummfondel's answer I changed the query to

```
select distinct adverts._id as _id, adverts.subCategory_id as subcategory_id, adverts.title as title, adverts.price as price, images.name as name, adverts.created_date as date from images,adverts where images.adverts_id=adverts._id and images.adverts_id not in(select images.adverts_id from images where images.default_img='1') group by adverts._id
union
select adverts._id as _id, adverts.subCategory_id as subcategory_id, adverts.title as title, adverts.price as price, images.name as name, adverts.created_date as date from images,adverts where images.adverts_id=adverts._id and default_img='1'
order by date
```

which gave me the desired result.
Thanks brummfondel.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right:

You want to get the row of images if default_img=='1'

```
select * from images where default_img='1'
```

otherwise you want to get the adverts row with id of adverts_id?

```
select * from images,adverts where images.adverts_id=adverts._id and images.default_img<>'1'
```

Make this one command:

```
select name,path,details from images,adverts where images.adverts_id=adverts._id and images.default_img<>'1'
union
select name,path,null from images where default_img='1'
```

You should specify the exact columns but not "*" in your final code.

Comment: It is actually gave me an error - Error while executing query: SELECTs to the left and right of UNION do not have the same number of result columns so I changed it to select * from images,adverts where images.adverts_id=adverts._id and images.default_img<>'1'
union
select * from images,adverts where images.adverts_id=adverts._id and default_img='1'
 and it returned all rows where as I wanted only one row corresponding to the row in adverts.

Comment: Yea, this is just a code example. You have to specify the columns in both selects and they have to be the same number of columns. You can fill it with ",0":

select name,path,0,0,0 ....

Like: select name,path,details from images,adverts where images.adverts_id=adverts._id and images.default_img<>'1'
union select name,path,0 from images where default_img='1'